# Create an Equinox instance of Karaf

Tags: configuration, osgi, apache-karaf

I am running Karaf 3.0.1 with Equinox core. Now I want to create a new instance which also runs Equinox core. I have tried:

```
instance:create test
```

The created instance runs Felix core so I tried to update its configuration `${karaf.home}/instances/test/etc/config.properties`. After adjusting, whenever I tried to connect to this instance, I received:

```
karaf@root: instance:connect test
Connecting to host localhost on port 8105
Error executing command: Failed to get the session
```

What wrong did I do? and Is there another way to create a Equinox core instance?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `instance:clone` rather than `instance:create`
2. Make sure you start the instance after you've created / cloned it
   before trying to connect.

i.e.

```
karaf@root()> bundle:list -t 0 | grep '^ 0'
 0 | Active   |   0 | 3.8.2.v20130124-134944 | OSGi System Bundle     
karaf@root()> instance:clone root test
karaf@root()> instance:list
SSH Port | RMI Registry | RMI Server | State   | PID   | Name
-------------------------------------------------------------
    8101 |         1099 |      44444 | Started | 29306 | root
    8101 |         1099 |      44444 | Stopped | 0     | test
karaf@root()> instance:ssh-port-change test 8102
karaf@root()> instance:rmi-server-port-change test 44445
karaf@root()> instance:rmi-registry-port-change test 1100
karaf@root()> instance:list
SSH Port | RMI Registry | RMI Server | State   | PID   | Name
-------------------------------------------------------------
    8101 |         1099 |      44444 | Started | 29306 | root
    8102 |         1100 |      44445 | Stopped | 0     | test
karaf@root()> instance:start test
karaf@root()> instance:connect test
Connecting to host localhost on port 8102
Connecting to unknown server. Automatically adding to known hosts.
Storing the server key in known_hosts.
Password:  *****
Connected
        __ __                  ____     
       / //_/____ __________ _/ __/     
      / ,<  / __ `/ ___/ __ `/ /_     
     / /| |/ /_/ / /  / /_/ / __/     
    /_/ |_|\__,_/_/   \__,_/_/     

  Apache Karaf (3.0.2)

Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands
and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command.
Hit 'system:shutdown' to shutdown Karaf.
Hit '<ctrl-d>' or type 'logout' to disconnect shell from current session.

karaf@test()> bundle:list -t 0 | grep '^ 0'
 0 | Active   |   0 | 3.8.2.v20130124-134944 | OSGi System Bundle     
karaf@test()>
```